# Solve equation with known variables and one unknown

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I'm trying to solve this equation in Matlab

```
dT=((-A-B*C+D*./E)
```

where `C=sin(dT)`. `dT` is unknown. `A`, `B`, `D`, and `E` are known variables. Using Matlab's `solve` function:

```
Ans=solve(dT==((-gra-H_vap*m_lg+grb*./ro_cp),dT);
```

But I receive an error message. How do I solve this equation?

Comment: 1. Make your post more readable (edit). 2. Add your error message.

Comment: And show all of your to provide a runnable example so others can try to replicate your issue. What values do your variable have and how do you create them? `grb*./ro_cp` is not valid Matlab and your parentheses don't even match.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given us any specifics on the values of your known parameters, and I also believe that `D*/E` in your example were intended to be a more valid expression.

Anyway, here is an example of how you make use of the symbolic solver `solve`:

```
syms dT

A = 1
B = 2
D = [1 2]
E = [3 4]
eqn = -A - B*sin(dT) + D/E - dT == 0

soldT = solve(eqn,dT)
```

which produces the following output

```
% ...

eqn =

- dT - 2*sin(dT) - 14/25 == 0

% ... 

soldT =

-0.18739659458654612052194305796251
```

See also [the language docs for `solve`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com).